# How to make Dialog Fulfilment Google Calendar integration work?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am new at node.js and I'm trying to build a chatbot using Dialogflow that lets you plan an appointment and inserts your appointment in a Google Calendar.  I seem to be getting the same error (No handler for requested intent) all the time, whatever I try.  Does anyone see what could be wrong or has tried this tutorial and has it working?

Things I tried:

- Updated my dependencies in the package.json
- Corrected the timezone (I live in Belgium/Europe) and timeZoneOffset
- Connected a billing account to the project in Google Cloud Platform

This is the tutorial I followed:

[GoogleCalendar Github](https://github.com/priyankavergadia/AppointmentScheduler-GoogleCalendar)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRa14.png) is a screenshot of the specific intent 'Schedule Appointment'.  It automatically goes to the default Response, but instead it should go to:
`Ok, let me see if we can fit you in. ${appointmentTimeString} is fine!.`
There is a custom entity in this intent: @AppointmentType with 2 options:
- vehicle registration
- driver's license

In the intent screenshot you also see that the time gives the date of today(in this case 2020-02-28), while it should give the requested date of the appointment (in this case 2020-03-10).  This might cause the error, but I don't know how to fix that in the inline editor.

My index.js from the Inline Editor (the calendar ID and service account data is correct, just took it out of here):

```js
 'use strict';

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const {google} = require('googleapis');
 const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 // const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
 // const xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');
 const axios = require('axios');
 
 // Enter your calendar ID below and service account JSON below
 const calendarId = "CALENDAR ID";
 const serviceAccount = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "PROJECT ID",
  "private_key_id": "PRIVATE KEY ID",
  "private_key": "PRIVATE KEY",
  "client_email": "CLIENT EMAIL",
  "client_id": "CLIENT ID",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}; // Starts with {"type": "service_account",...
 
 // Set up Google Calendar Service account credentials
 const serviceAccountAuth = new google.auth.JWT({
   email: serviceAccount.client_email,
   key: serviceAccount.private_key,
   scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
 });
 
 const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
 process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
 const timeZone = 'Europe/Madrid';
 const timeZoneOffset = '+01:00';
 
 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
   const appointment_type = agent.parameters.AppointmentType;
   function makeAppointment (agent) {
     // Calculate appointment start and end datetimes (end = +1hr from start)
     const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time + timeZoneOffset));
     // const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('+')[0]));
     const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
     const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
       'en-GB',
       { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone}
     );
 
     // Check the availibility of the time, and make an appointment if there is time on the calendar
     return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type).then(() => {
       agent.add(`Ok, let me see if we can fit you in. ${appointmentTimeString} is fine!.`);
     }).catch(() => {
       agent.add(`I'm sorry, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString}.`);
     });
   }
 
   let intentMap = new Map();
   intentMap.set('Schedule Appointment', makeAppointment);
   agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
 });
 
 function createCalendarEvent (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     calendar.events.list({
       auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
       calendarId: calendarId,
       timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
       timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
     }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
       // Check if there is a event already on the Calendar
       if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
         reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
       } else {
         // Create event for the requested time period
         calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
           calendarId: calendarId,
           resource: {summary: appointment_type +' Appointment', description: appointment_type,
             start: {dateTime: dateTimeStart},
             end: {dateTime: dateTimeEnd}}
         }, (err, event) => {
           err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
         }
         );
       }
     });
   });
 }
```

My package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "Dialogflow fulfillment for the bike shop sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "semistandard --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0", 
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.4.2",
    "apiai": "^4.0.3",
    "xoauth2": "^1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2"
  }
}
```

This is the error I get in my Google Cloud Platform Logs Viewer:
[Google Cloud Platform error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jULjL.png)

This is the error I get in my Firebase console:
[Firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am3WG.png)

Comment: The error suggests a problem with your Intents and how you're triggering it. Can you update your question to illustrate what the conversation has looked like when the error happens? It might also help to show a screen shot of the Intent that you think should be triggered.

Comment: I think you provided all the necessary information needed. The one thing that comes to mind for me is making sure your webhook is enabled in the Dialogflow console. You can see this if you scroll all the way to the bottom of your intent.

Comment: Thanks for the reactions guys,  didn't work yet but I keep on trying

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be reading in a parameter before the agent routes your request to the correct function. Try removing that line that's above your function makeAppointment inside the function like so..

```
   function makeAppointment (agent) {
     // Calculate appointment start and end datetimes (end = +1hr from start)
     const appointment_type = agent.parameters.AppointmentType;
     const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time + timeZoneOffset));
```

Hopefully this works for you as everything else seems to be sest up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems alright.
Try to use default package.json.

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

FYI, Node 6 is depreciated in Google Cloud Function.
Otherwise you could test dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment in Google Cloud Function environment to get the root cause.

[image: Node 6]